# C# Group DataRows in DataTable

Tags: c#, email, datatable, datarow

I have a `DataTable` with two columns: `File` & `Email`

```
C://file1.jpg aaa@gmail.com  
C://file2.jpg aaa@gmail.com  
C://file3.jpg bbb@gmail.com  
C://file4.jpg ccc@gmail.com  
C://file5.jpg bbb@gmail.com
```

In my code i loop through the `DataRow`s and send an email to `Email` with `File` attached.

**Problem:**

I need to somehow check if there are any other `DataRow`s with the same `Email` and if so, send just one email with multiple attachments.

So the above `DataTable` would result in 3 emails:

```
file1,file2 sent to aaa@gmail.com  
file3,file5 sent to bbb@gmail.com  
file4 sent to ccc@gmail.com
```

My code sample:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
     string file = row[0].ToString();
     string email = row[1].ToString();
     SendEmailWithAttachments(email,file);
}
```

I could pass a `StringCollection` or an array to my `SendEmailWithAttachments()` function then loop throught it and attach all the files, but how do I group these `DataRow`s in first place

Comment: What about [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx) email?

Comment: Probably the first thing to do is to change that _SendEmailWithAttachments_ to accept a `List<string>` with the names of the files for the current email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx) Linq extension you could handle your DataRows grouping them for the Email field, then foreach create a list of strings with the file names.

Of course, you need also to change the SendMailWithAttachments to receive as second parameter a `List<string>` instead of a single string

```
var g = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(d => d.Field<string>("Email"));
foreach (var x in g)
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    foreach (var z in x)
        files.Add(z.Field<string>("File"));

    SendEmailWithAttachments(email,files);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use GroupBy to group by email:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Path");
        dt.Columns.Add("Email");
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr.ItemArray=new object[2]{"C://file1.jpg", "aaa@gmail.com"};
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr.ItemArray=new object[2]{"C://file2.jpg", "aaa@gmail.com"};
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr.ItemArray=new object[2]{"C://file3.jpg", "bbb@gmail.com"};
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr.ItemArray=new object[2]{"C://file4.jpg", "ccc@gmail.com"};
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr.ItemArray=new object[2]{"C://file5.jpg", "bbb@gmail.com"};
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        var grouped=dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("Email"));

        foreach (var mail in grouped)
        {
            List<string> filesForEmail = new List<string>();
            foreach (var file in mail)
            {
                filesForEmail.Add(file.Field<string>("Path"));
            }

            SendEmailWithAttachments(mail.Key, filesForEmail);
        }
```